# What are Desktop.ini files and how to get rid of them?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems

Sometimes I notice Desktop.ini files in folders of my computer. Why/how are they generated, and, is it possible to make the OS stop generating these files?

Comment: These files are the plague of obsessive compulsive computer users that need to show hidden files and folders. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Desktop.ini` is a Windows system file that stores information about customisation in each folder (one file per customised folder). E.g. on the desktop or in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs`.

If you customise folders then you can't avoid them, but you can hide them.

Enable these two in a Windows Explorer window, menu Tools/Folder Options/tab View/:

1. "Do not show hidden files and folders"
2. "Hide protected operating system files (recommended)"